# Заливка страницы

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

[image: Картинка]

У меня нет возможности закрасить страницу с помощью css через тег body.Я создаю отдельный тег для содержимого страницы и закрашиваю его.При margin-top появляется такой артифакт.Как под другому закрасить страницу или изменить положение.

Comment: А почему вы не можете использовать стили для `body`?

Comment: Вы можете сделать padding-top и тогда background не будет смещаться:)

Comment: Хотелось бы всё же увидеть Ваш код